# Cannot delete file because it is used by another process

Tags: wpf, multithreading, file-io

I'm getting this exception

> The process cannot access the file 'myfile.zip' because it is being used by another process.

When I try to delete a file. I understand the error, but I'm not sure what other process could be using the file.

I'm downloading the file via [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) asynchronously, but I cancel the download before trying to delete it, which means that process should relinquish it, no?

Here are the relevant methods. It's a simple file-downloader:

```
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    string downloadFile = textBox1.Text.Trim();
    if (e.Key == Key.Return && downloadFile != "")
    {
        var dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
        dlg.FileName = Path.GetFileName(downloadFile);
        dlg.DefaultExt = Path.GetExtension(downloadFile);
        var result = dlg.ShowDialog();
        if(result.Value)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
            textBox1.Focus();
            _saveFile = dlg.FileName;
            progressBar1.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => progressBar1.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0))));
            _webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(downloadFile), _saveFile);
        }
    }
}


private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (_webClient.IsBusy && _saveFile != null)
    {
        var result = MessageBox.Show("Download in progress. Are you sure you want to exit?", "Exit?", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            _webClient.CancelAsync();
            File.Delete(_saveFile);
        }
        else
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait when downloading realy canceled. When call _webClient.CancelAsync(); next operator executes immediatley before webClient canceled.

May be you need delete the file in callback of CancelAsync(...)

Comment: So how do I know when it's finished cancelling? I don't see an event for "DownloadCancelled". I figured `CancelAsync` was synchronous. **Edit:** Nevermind. Reading [the remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.cancelasync%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explains it.